# PHP Ldap profile user with its nested groups

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I need to get some user attributes from Active Directory via ldap query.
I'm using this code:

```
$attributes=array("cn","sAMAccountName","sn","givenname","memberof","mail","telephonenumber","mobile","useraccountcontrol","department");
$filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=".$username."))";
$result = ldap_search($ldaphandler, $domain, $filter, $attributes);
```

I need all nested groups, but with this query I get only the first-level group (memberof field). But for instance if a users is member of InnerGroup and InnerGroup is member of OuterGroup I would like to get both groups (InnerGroup and OuterGroup). Is it possibile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To find all the groups that "user1" is a member of (see [AD search filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

1. Set the base to the groups container DN; for example root DN (dc=dom,dc=fr)
2. Set the scope to subtree
3. Use the following filter : (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x)

Example with LDIFDE.EXE (native command line AD search on windows) :

```
ldifde -f t.txt -d "DC=dom,DC=fr" -r "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=jblanc,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr)"
```